# How to update the values in Table using Realm android?

Tags: android, realm

I have table say **Student** .I want to updated the values in the table and it does not have any primary key.
I am using Realm Database for the same.

Comment: You need to be more specific. How would you find which object to update if you cannot identify it (ie. has a primary key). Alternatively, if you don't have any other objects linking to your table, you can just clear the table and insert the data again.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assume You have `VisitingCardPOJO` you can find element depending on **"no"** use `findFirst()` if you want to update only first element or you can use `findAll()`  you get list of record then you update same way below using `for` loop

```
public void updateNewCard(Realm realm, VisitingCardPOJO card) {
            VisitingCardPOJO toEdit = realm.where(VisitingCardPOJO.class)
                    .equalTo("no", card.getNo()).findFirst();
            realm.beginTransaction();
            toEdit.setName(card.getName());
            toEdit.setAddress(card.getAddress());
            realm.commitTransaction();
        }
```

Comment: Is it possible to update without having primary key?

Answer (score 2):

note that  Realm will delete that object if the new data or if input is empty that you want to update .thus why one would see that their data disappearing or getting deleted suddenly.